# Is it possible to ignore xcodebuild analyze warnings from cocoapods and SPM packages?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I use `xcodecode analyze` to help find static analysis warnings in my code when running CI builds (similar to running the `Analyze` tool in Xcode directly).

It works great finding issues - but the problem is it picks up issues in all code, even that which I do not have control over, i.e. dependencies brought in from cocoapods and SPM packages.

Is there a way to exclude these dependencies and only have it report issues in my own code?